# Hold/Push Button with Raspberry Pi GPIO

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, raspberry-pi, gpio

I would like my button to do 2 of the following things;

- Do something whenever a button is pushed
- Do something whenever a button is held for a certain amount of time (2seconds)

The current code that I'm working with looks a little like this:

```
    //Comfirming a letter or sending the word.
    private void btnRightValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if button is pressed it will confirm a letter
        if (e.Edge == GpioPinEdge.FallingEdge)
        {
            //code to confirm letter
            ConfirmLetter();

            //if(buttonHeldForAWhile)
            //{
            //Send message
            //SendWord();
            //}
        }
    }
```

But how can I check whether the button is held for 2 or 3 seconds?

Comment: Can't you just check if  `GpioPinValue.Low` is true, and check that vs. the system clock?

Comment: By the way, here's the MS reference for the gpio namespace in case anyone is interested: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.gpio.aspx

Comment: *"I would like my button to do..."* -- Your specification is imprecise.  Most event reporting schemes use edge detection rather than level detection, so they report both a switch closure (e.g. button press) and a switch open (e.g. button release).  Is first *"something"*  action performed as soon as button is pressed (without waiting for release)?  So should both *"something"* actions be done when the button is pressed ***and*** held for 2 sec?  What should be done if the button is held for more than 3 sec?  Repeat the action?

Comment: @sawdust, I thought his question was pretty clear. If button is held for 2 seconds, then do something, like his code comments state. And I believe there IS a level detector for the gpio, like I mentioned.

Comment: press would be hold and release (quickly so to speak), and hold is press and hold the button for 2 seconds before releasing it. I would like to give 2 separate functions to each 'event'.

Comment: *"**press** would be **hold** and release ..., and **hold** is **press** and hold the button for 2 seconds before releasing it."* -- That's only a partial specification; unhandled situations leads to undefined behavior and bugs.  It's also a ***recursive*** explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix my problem by using a Stopwatch that measures the time that the button is being pressed.

Above our namespace we need to add this in order for us to use the Stopwatch class.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Now we want to declare a Stopwatch by:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch;
```

When the button is pressed and held my code will pick that up with the `FallingEdge`. When it is pressed I also want it to create a new Stopwatch and start it.

When the button is released, which is checked by `RisingEdge`. I stop the timer and get the time between the 2 events. I then compare the time pressed in an if statement so I can decide what to do with the buttonpress. In this case SendWord, or Append current char and preview it.

```
    //Comfirming the chosen letter.
    private void btnRightValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Edge == GpioPinEdge.FallingEdge)
        {
            stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
        }

        if (e.Edge == GpioPinEdge.RisingEdge)
        {
            stopWatch.Stop();
            long duration = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            if (duration > 2000 )
            {
                SendWord();
            }
            else
            {
                //Add the current character to the word
                _currentWordSB.Append(Convert.ToString(_currentChar));

            //    //Reset currentChar aswell
                _currentChar = ' ';

            //    //The user confirmed the morse sequence and wants to start a new one, so we reset it.
                _morseCode.Clear();

            //    //Preview the word
                PreviewLetter();
            }
        }
    }
```

If there is any better way to tackle my problem, please let me know but so far this solution works for me.

I needed this as I was working on a Raspberry Pi project with Morse code input via buttons. That input then had to be displayed on a LCD screen. If the user was satisfied with his input he could then send it to the other user(s) by holding the Right button for 2 seconds.